# Access to private folder

Tags: linux, directory

I am using PHP Zend 1 and I am having a problem. I made a folder called "invoice" and it is not in the www folder. So the problem is that I don't have access to this folder when do have the right path to this folder: `PUBLIC_PATH . '/../invoice/`

This is because of Linux. Does anyone know how I can have access to this folder? 
I would like to view the files in this folder on my site.

Comment: Where is the current invoice folder present and it's permissions and owner

Comment: The invoice folder is current in the data folder. Data folder is in my project folder. I couldn't change the permissions, because there are no permissions for this folder. Thanks for your help anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume Apache? If so, symlink the `invoice` to your www root and set `Options FollowSymLinks` in the apache config.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Check for the folder permissions using `ls -la`, it should be **755** by default. Now also check the owner of folder.

```
use chmod and chown commands to change the permissions and moderators of the folder
```